# Counting Element Permutation check

Tags: java

In the codility permutation check question:

```
A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to N once, and only once.
For example, array A such that:
    A[0] = 4
    A[1] = 1
    A[2] = 3
    A[3] = 2
is a permutation, but array A such that:
    A[0] = 4
    A[1] = 1
    A[2] = 3
is not a permutation.
The goal is to check whether array A is a permutation.
Write a function:
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
that, given a zero-indexed array A, returns 1 if array A is a permutation and 0 if it is not.
For example, given array A such that:
    A[0] = 4
    A[1] = 1
    A[2] = 3
    A[3] = 2
the function should return 1.
Given array A such that:
    A[0] = 4
    A[1] = 1
    A[2] = 3
the function should return 0.
Assume that:
N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].
Complexity:
expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Here is my solution to it, but I have an error. I feel, I need to check for one extra condition before the code can work well. When tested with an array like this: A[4,1,3}, it returned 1 instead of 0 . What else do I need to test for to get this code to work perfectly? I am missing it because I don't see why a[]{4,1,3} is NOT a permutation and why A[] {4,1,3,2} is a permutation in the question. If anyone could explain that, I might be able to solve my problem. Now,I did modify it to work now on my eclipse,tested but on codility, I still keep getting error about the line : `counter[A[i]] += 1`; Any one knows why this is so? Something that the array is out of bound but I didn't get that error on my eclipse IDE.
Thanks

```
    public class Solution {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 7
        int[] counter = new int[(A[0] * A.length)];
        int max = -1;
        int OccurBefore = -1; // store some random number for a start

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

            if (A[i] > max) {
                max = A[i];
            } 
                if (A[i] == OccurBefore) {
                    return 0;
                }

                if(A[i] != OccurBefore) {
                    OccurBefore = A[i];
                    counter[A[i]] += 1;

                }

        }

        if(A.length<max){
            return 0;
        }

        return 1;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution scores 100 in codility:

```
/**
* https://codility.com/demo/results/demoYEU94K-8FU/ 100
*/
public class PermCheck {
  public static final int NOT_PERMUTATION = 0;
  public static final int PERMUTATION = 1;
  // (4,1,3,2) = 1
  // (4,1,3) = 0
  // (1) = 1
  // () = 1
  // (2) = 0
  public int solution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int[] mark = new int[A.length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
        int value = A[i];
        if(value >= mark.length) {
             return NOT_PERMUTATION;
        }
        if(mark[value] == 0) {
            mark[value]=1;
        } else {
            return NOT_PERMUTATION;
        }
    }

    return PERMUTATION;
  }
}
```

You can also see it here:
https://github.com/moxi/codility-lessons/blob/master/Codility/CountingElements/PermCheck.java
along with some others.

Answer (score 3):

This is **Java** solutions that score **100%**.

```
import java.util.*; 

class Solution 
{
  public int solution(int[] A) 
  {
      Arrays.sort(A);

      // to remove duplicates
      Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
      for(int i : A)
      {
          set.add(i);
      }

      List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
      int array_size = A.length;
      int value = 1;

      if (array_size != list.size() || list.get(0) != 1 || list.get(list.size() - 1) != array_size)
          value = 0;

      return value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works fine.

1. Sort array
2. Check every pair of adjacent elements. If right element != left Element + 1,

then the array is not a permutation

```
public class permutation {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] A={2,3,7,4,5,8,6,9,10,11};

    Arrays.sort(A);

    boolean perm = true;


    for (int i=0; i<A.length-1; i++){
      if(A[i+1]!= A[i]+1 ){
          perm = false;

      }

    }
    System.out.println(perm);
}

}
```

Comment: If you are sorting the array, you don't need to iterate over the array again, you can just check the first and last elements, the first has to be equal to 1 and the last element has to be equal to A.length. Anyway this is not O (n) it might be in the best case scenario O(n log n) in terms of time, because Arrays.sort isn't O(n) in time complexity.

Comment: @moxi Not correct answer. The array can have duplicate elements and therefore not be a permutation (ie. all elements unique), and still have first and last to be fine.

Comment: @tas Sorting array will work as correct solution but will fail at efficiency test. In other words it will go to timeout when the array has more that 1,000,000  elements which is a few of the test cases.

Answer (score 2):

Python solution that got me 100% results

```
def solution(A):

    le = len(A)
    A = list(set(A))

    if le != len(A):
        return 0

    le = len(A)

    if le != max(A):
        return 0

    return 1
```

Comment: I think this is the best Python solution so far.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to improve your approach to this problem:

- The "max" variable isn't really necessary, as you can just compare the values of the array to the length of the array. If any of them exceed the length, you can just break out of program with a return of 0
- I'm confused as to what you're trying to achieve with your "Counter" array. When you instantiate it, you're instantiating it with a length of length of A multiplied by A[0]. Considering A[0] could be any value (or in the example question A[0] can be 1,2,3,4) you can't really know what to expect as a length for your "counter" array. If you want a "counter" array that is the same length as the A array (which I used in my solution), use the following:

  ```
  int[] counter = new int[A.length];
  ```
- The occurBefore concept is interesting, but you have to consider that the Array can be any length. So if we have an array of {2,3,2,4,5,6}, your occurBefore values will be 2, then you will compare 2 with 3, change occurBefore to 3 and then compare 2 to 3. Even though 2 exists twice in the array, your occurBefore comparison will never reveal this.

Hint: you can use 2 for loops, one to populate an array with "legal" values, one to confirm the populated array contains the 1 -> N numbers that it would need to contain to be a valid permutation.

Answer (score 1):

**100% Result : PHP Code for PermCheck Codility**

```
function solution($A) {
    $count_of_elements  = array_fill(0, count($A)+1, null);
    for($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++ ){

        if($A[$i] > count($A) || $A[$i] <= 0)
            return 0;
        $count_of_elements[$A[$i]] += 1;

        if($count_of_elements[$A[$i]] > 1)
            return 0;        
    }
    if(array_sum($count_of_elements) < count($A))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I did not understand the last condition after the loop ends. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Isn't that already being covered by the two if conditions inside the loop ?

Answer (score 1):

I've used Set for the solution:

```
import java.util.*;

class Solution {

    public int solution(int[] A) {

        final Set perm = new HashSet();
        final int size = A.length;

        for(int number : A)
        {
            if(number > size)
                return 0;

            perm.add(number);
        }

        if(perm.size() == A.length)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: one small optimization: you could add  if(!perm.add(number)) { return 0; }

Answer (score 1):

[image]

My take on the problem with Python 3.6... based on various ideas (a big thank you)

```
def solution(A):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    if len(A) == 0:
        return 0

    max_element = max(A)
    if max_element - len(A) > 1:
        return 0

    actual_sum = sum(A)
    check_sum = sum(range(1, len(set(A)) + 1))

    if actual_sum != check_sum:
        return 0

    return 1
```

Comment: This solution probably wouldn't work in other languages for bigger numbers, since

`N is an integer within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000]`

Answer (score 1):

```
  public int solution(int[] A)
    {

        int xorsum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
        {
            xorsum = (i + 1) ^ A[i] ^ xorsum;

        }
        if (xorsum > 0)
            return 0;
        return 1;
      }
```

this also gives 100% in codility but here not used array all xor based check same time but no additional memory use code in c#

Comment: This is one of the best solution here for each language!

Answer (score 0):

By definition of a permutation you need to have exactly one of each number, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation

Try first with a doubly nested loop, this is not the required answer as it require O(N^2) complexity, but its the simplest algorithm.

One problem is you not using your counter array, you settting but not reading values. I can't quite understand why its size has A[0]*A.length. A[0] is not special as (3,2,4,1) or (1,2,3,4) could be valid permutations.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your input. I could modify the A[0]*A.length part. My big question is why is A[0]= 4, A[1] = 1, A[2] = 3 NOT a permutation? These numbers occured once. That is the part I am still not clear about.

Comment: You would need A[0]= 4, A[1] = 1, A[2] = 3, A[3]=2 to make it a permutation. If you think of a permutation as a way of arranging the numbers 1,2,3,4 so each number must appear exactly once.

Comment: please how could I have allocated a better size to the counter array? You mentioned why itz size has A[0]*A.length? Well, I tried with A.length and I didn't get the answer. Any better way to fix this problem?

Comment: I'd just use `int[] counter = new int[A.length];` But not actually sure how you intend your algorithm to work and what purpose of the counter array is.

Comment: One point the problem with `counter[A[i]] += 1` is due to the fact that arrays have an index starting 0 upto length -1. So is A[i]=4 and counter has 4 elements counter[A[i]] will cause an error. You probably want `counter[A[i]-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the problem is kinda confusing. It actually wants you to check if the array contains 1..N integers (no duplicates or missing number).

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 7
        int[] count = new int[A.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

            int x = A[i]-1;

            if (x >= A.length) return 0;

            int check = count[x];

            if (check > 0) return 0;

            count[x] = 1;
        }

        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**100/% for PHP PermCheck Codility, Bit more optimized**

```
function solution($A) {
    $count_of_elements  = array_fill(0, count($A)+1, null);
    for($i=0; $i < count($A); $i++ ){

        $count_of_elements[$A[$i]] += 1;

        if($A[$i] > count($A) || $A[$i] <= 0 || $count_of_elements[$A[$i]] > 1)
            return 0;

    }
    if(array_sum($count_of_elements) < count($A))
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple php 100/100 solution

```
function solution($A) {
    $count = count($A);
    if (count(array_unique($A)) != $count) return 0;
    $sum = array_sum($A);
    $should_be = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
        $should_be += $i;
    }
    return intval($sum == $should_be);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Scala solution that gets 100/100. Find it more elegant in Scala

```
object Solution {
    def solution(A: Array[Int]): Int = {
        if (A.max == A.length && A.distinct.size == A.length)
            1
        else
            0
    }
}
```

Comment: The only thing is that this is O(N log N) solution.

Comment: Not understanding why it is  O(N log N)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution in Scala: http://geeks.aretotally.in/codility-permcheck-in-scala/.

```
import java.util.BitSet
```

object Solution {
    def solution(A: Array[Int]): Int = {
        val bitz = new BitSet(A.size + 1)

`val good = A.foldLeft(true)((current, i) => 
        if (current) {
            (i, bitz.get(i)) match {
                case (x, _) if x > A.size => 
                    false

                case (x, _) if x < 1 || x > 1000000000 => 
                    false

                case (0, _) => 
                    false

                case (_, true) => 
                    false

                case _ =>
                    bitz.set(i)
                    true
            }

        } else false
    )

    if (good && A.size > 0 && A.size <= 100000) 1
    else 0
}`

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    boolean[] cloned = new boolean[A.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if(A[i] > A.length){
            return 0;
        }
        cloned[A[i]-1] = true;
    }

    for (boolean val:
         cloned) {
        if(!val)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
```

This solution got 100 and complete

Answer (score 0):

If permutation is, as task description states, a sequence containing each element from **1** to N once, and only once, then one could do it like this:

```
public int solution(int... A) {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    // calculating sum of permutation elements
    int sum = A.length * (A.length +1) /2;
    for(int i=0; i<A.length;i++){
        set.add(A[i]);
        sum -=A[i];
        }
    // return 0 if either sizes don't much or there was some 
    // number/s missing in permutation and thus sum !=0;
    return ((set.size() == A.length) && sum ==0)? 1 : 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby 100%:

```
def solution(a)
  values = a.uniq
  is_ok = 0
  if values.length == a.length
    is_ok = (a.length == a.max) ? 1 : 0
  end

  is_ok
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortcode is beautiful. take a vector mark all of them as 1. Then iterate over given vector and to mark present bits as 0. Now find the non zero elements. If present return 0  or else return 1
[image]

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int solution(vector<int> &A) {

    vector<int> range(A.size(),1);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i < A.size(); i++){
        if(A[i] <= A.size() && A[i] > 0)
            range[A[i]-1] = 0;
    }

    for(unsigned int i=0; i < A.size(); i++)
        if(range[i]) return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> A = {4, 1, 3, 2};
    cout << solution(A);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 Solution**

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int{

    let resultValue = 1

    A = A.sorted{$0 > $1}

    let lastIndex : Int = A.last ?? 0

    if lastIndex != 1 {
        return 0
    }

    for index in stride(from: 0, to: A.count - 1, by: 1){
        if (A[index] - 1) != A[index + 1]{
            return 0
        }
    }

    return resultValue

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one liner - sum of first n natural numbers

`if (a.sum == (a.size * (a.size+1))/2 && a.max == a.distinct.length) 1 else 0`

Answer (score 0):

public static int solution(int[] A) {
          int N = A.length;
          return ((((N*(N+1))/2)-IntStream.of(A).distinct().filter(i-> i>=1 && i<=N).sum())==0)?1:0;
    }

PS: import java.util.stream.IntStream;

Answer (score 0):

[Codility with 100%](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingEBQW3A-6N8/)

Solution in python with description - easy to understand-

```
def solution(ar):
"""
https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingEBQW3A-6N8/
100%
idea is use xor - xor of two same number cancel the same bits and make that to zero
do xor of all elements of array
do xor of 1 to length plus 1
at last xor of all should be zero

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.
A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to N once, and only once.
:param ar:
:return:
"""
xor_sum = 0
# xor of 1 to len ar
# xor of all elements of existing array
for index in range(1, len(ar) + 1):
    xor_sum = xor_sum ^ index ^ ar[index - 1]
# at the end xor sum should be zero
if xor_sum == 0:
    return 1
else:
    return 0


 arr = [1, 2]
 result = solution(arr)
 print("Sol " + str(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using JavaScript **tested 100%**.

```
function solution(A) {
    A.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    let bool = 1;
    if(A[0] === 1) {
        for(let i=0; i<A.length; i++) {
            if((i+1) < A.length) {
                if(A[i] != A[i+1] - 1) {
                    bool = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        bool = 0;
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**: these are my two solutions, both with time complexity: O(N) or O(N * log(N))

```
//ask Score 100%  | Correctness 100% | Performance 100%
function solution(A) {
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (arr[A[i] - 1] == 1) return 0; //exit for duplicated
    arr[A[i] - 1] = 1;
  }
  if (arr[0] == 1)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if (!arr[i]) return 0; //no number in this position
    }
  else return 0; // first number not is 1;
  return 1;
}

//ask Score 100%  | Correctness 100% | Performance 100%
function solution(A) {
  A.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    if (A[i] != i + 1) return 0; //isn't a number for this position
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Below solution given me 100%

public int solution100(int[] A) {
        if (A.length == 0)
            return 0;

        if (A.length == 1 && A[0] != 1)
            return 0;

        int len = A.length;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        Set<Integer> hSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            if (max < A[i])
                max = A[i];

            hSet.add(A[i]);
        }// for_i

        int s_size = hSet.size();
            
        if (s_size == len && max == len)
            return 1;
    enter code here
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: enter code here  <= Remove this line by mistake added while posting. It java 8 solution

Answer (score 0):

A java solution that gave me 100/100

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A) {
        
        int sumOfNPlusOne = ((A.length)*(A.length+1))/2;
        boolean sumStatus = false;
        int arrayEleSum = 0;
        for(int a: A){
            arrayEleSum+=a;
        }
        if(arrayEleSum == sumOfNPlusOne) sumStatus = true;

        if(!sumStatus) return 0;


        boolean[] status = new boolean[A.length+1];
        status[0]=true;
        for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++){
            if(A[i]>=status.length) continue;
            if(!(status[A[i]])){
                status[A[i]] = true;
            }
        }

        boolean missingStatus = false;
        for(boolean stat: status){
            if(!stat){
                missingStatus = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!missingStatus)return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public int solution(int[]A) {

    Arrays.sort(A);
    for(int i=0; i<A.length;i++) {
        if (A[i]!=i+1) {
            System.out.println("0");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("1");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: add some information to your answer like what you're doing and why, why your answer is correct or what differs your answer from others. As only code answers aren't very helpful.

Comment: N log N complexity .