# check if the numbers in the array between 0-array.length -1

Tags: java

I need to write a program that will check that all the numbers inside the array will be between `0` to `array.length-1`, and will occur just once, returning true or false.

For example `[0,1,3,2]` will return True, and `[4,3.0,1]` and `[0,1,2,2]` will both return False.

I've try to write it :

```
public static boolean isPermutation (int[] array) {
    boolean isPermutation =true ;
      for (int i = 0 ; i<array.length & isPermutation; i = i+1) {
          for (int j = 1 ; j<array.length & isPermutation; j = j+1) {
              if (array[i]==array[j]|(array[i]>=array.length)) {
                  isPermutation =false ;
              }
          }
      }
      return isPermutation ;
}
```

the problem is that when we check `array[i]==array[j]` its equal when `i` equals `j` and not the numbers in the array.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Why is `[4,3.0,1]` false? Also its not possible given that your array is `int[]`

Comment: @NicholasK 4 is greater than `array.length-1` (dot was most likely a typo).

Comment: `for (int j = 1` should probably be `for (int j = i+ 1` to: avoid situation where i==j; also there is no need to compare same pair twice (a==b) and later (b==a). BTW you can use Sets to check if elements are unique.

Comment: Copy the array, sort the copy, then iterate thru sorted copy checking that `sortedCopy[i]==i` for all `i:  0<= i < sortedCopy.length`.

Comment: you need to check the condition for element >0  , i.e if (array[i]==array[j]||(array[i]>=array.length) || array[i] < 0) and the inner loop you can have for(int j = i+1; j<array.length && isPermutation; j++ ) . check the last number is within 0 and array.length -1. you problem would be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect a permutation of sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257735/detect-a-permutation-of-sequence)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579054/counting-element-permutation-check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid for loop within a for loop and can use mathematics to your advantage and keep adding all the numbers and finally check if the actual sum is equal to the intended sum then return true else false. If all the numbers are withing range and exactly appear once, only then their sum will be equal to the sum of all numbers 1 to N. Meanwhile while scanning the numbers in array, if you encounter any number greater than array length - 1 or less than zero, you can immediately return false.

Here is the kind of code that may help.

```
public static boolean areNumbersInclusive(int[] arr) {
    long sum = 0;

    for (int n : arr) {
        if (n > arr.length - 1 || n < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        sum += n;
    }

    long intendedSum = ((arr.length - 1) * arr.length) / 2; // sum from 1 to n is n*(n+1)/2

    return intendedSum == sum;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr1 = {1,0,5,3,2,4};
    int[] arr2 = {1,0,3,4};
    int[] arr3 = {-1,0,3,2};
    int[] arr4 = {1,0,3,2};

    System.out.println(areNumbersInclusive(arr1));
    System.out.println(areNumbersInclusive(arr2));
    System.out.println(areNumbersInclusive(arr3));
    System.out.println(areNumbersInclusive(arr4));
}
```

This prints following output as expected.

```
true
false
false
true
```

Here is OP's correct version of method, although nested for loop can be avoided with my answer.

```
public static boolean isPermutation(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] >= array.length || array[i] < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you  . but can u tell me what he problem with the code that i wrote ?

Comment: One problem I see you didn't use OR properly. You need to write || instead of | when doing OR in comparison. You should write if (array[i]==array[j] || (array[i]>=array.length)) instead of if (array[i]==array[j]|(array[i]>=array.length)) Single | is called bitwise OR operation. Same goes for & that you have written. You need to write && for And operation and there could be more logical issues. Let me check your method in detail.

Comment: ok thank i will try.. the broblem that i do debug i see that inside the loop it check if iand j equal and not the number inside the array.. its doesnt check if array[i]==array[j]

Comment: @EladSolomon: As I checked, there were multiple problems in your code. Main problem was, you were comparing array[i]==array[j] and at point where i and j were equal, it use to set isPermutation = false due to which it always returned false. I have edited my answer to include the correct version of your method. You can have a look of what all changes I have made there.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

By using a `Set` you can easily check if there are the same numbers inside the array, because a set stores only 1 occurrence of each number and then in one loop you check if all the numbers are in the range 0..array.length-1:

```
public static boolean isPermutation (Integer[] array) {
    int length = array.length;

    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
    if (set.size() < length)
        return false;

    for (int x : array) {
        if ((x < 0) || (x > length - 1))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] a = {0, 1, 3, 2};
    Integer[] b = {0, 1, 3, 1};
    Integer[] c = {0, 1, 3, -1};

    System.out.println(isPermutation(a));
    System.out.println(isPermutation(b));
    System.out.println(isPermutation(c));
}
```

will print:

```
true
false
false
```

Or even better avoid the loop by filtering the `Set` to a `List` with only the valid values and check the list's size if it is equal to the array's length:

```
public static boolean isPermutation (Integer[] array) {
    int length = array.length;
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array));
    if (set.size() < length)
        return false;
    List<Integer> list = set.stream().filter(x -> x >= 0 && x < length).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return list.size() == length;
}
```